# How to solve a logical problem in NestGraph

Tags: function-construction, graphs-and-networks

`NestGraph` have two usage like
[image]

I realize it will conflict sometimes.There is a code like

```
Pos = Catenate[CoordinateBoundingBoxArray[{{1, 1}, {9, 10}}]];
NestGraph[Function[ever, 
  Select[Pos, EuclideanDistance[ever, #] == Sqrt[5] &]], {8, 
  1}, 2, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`NestGraph` will call the second method to run my code.Actually I hope it run with first usage.And the below graph is expected.

[image]

How should I adjust this code?

Comment: What is *ever*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny tunning.Deserve to share.:)

```
Pos = f @@@ Catenate[CoordinateBoundingBoxArray[{{1, 1}, {9, 10}}]];
NestGraph[
 Function[ever, 
  Select[Pos, 
   EuclideanDistance[List @@ ever, List @@ #] == Sqrt[5] &]], 
 f[8, 1], 2, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]